# Error in adding the web references

Tags: asp.net, web-services

i created a Myservice.asmx and it's working fine all the methods i am ble to invoke,giving me the correct but when i adding my MyService.asmx to my wwebsite as areferences giving me the following error.

There was an erroe in downloading 'http://localhost:49211/Myservice.asmx'
unable to connect to the remote server No connection could be made because the targer machine actively refused '127.0.0.1.49211'
There was an erroe in downloading 'http://localhost:49211/Myservice.asmx/$metadata/'

aAny Suggestions to solve this....Error..

Comment: what happens when you use a web browser to view http://localhost:49211/Myservice.asmx/

Comment: Showing the methods in the web browser and are working..Daniel

Answer (score 0):

"actively refused" often means that the connection simply couldn't get through and is usually a firewall / router issue to forward and allow the necessary ports through.